# Whom-clause Vs who-clause

Tags: relative-clauses, who-whom

Michael Swan refers to the whom-clause as "not generally considered correct." In his book, he mentions an example for a 'whom-clause' :

> This is a letter from my
>   father, whom we hope will be out of hospital soon.

He says the above sentence will be "more correct"  with **who** in place of **whom**.

**My questions**

1. Is the the sentence with **whom** still correct?
2. I always thought that **whom** is used in relation to an *object* rather than a *subject*, as in:

> She is the woman whom you met at my wedding last year.

Restrictiveness aside, I see no difference between Swan's sentence and the above example. Am I missing something here?

Comment: To see the difference, try extracting the whom-clause from the rest of the sentence and see if it makes more sense with he/she or him/her.  We hope *him* will be out of hospital soon?  No, we hope *he* will, so it must be *who*.  You met *her* at the wedding or you met *she* at the wedding?  You met *her*, so it must be *whom*.

Comment: @stangdon That should be written as an answer.

Comment: A pertinent thread is [**here,**](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/196105191/p/1) complete with quotes from Swan. It's _who_ by a landslide on the OP's question.

Comment: @JamesK - Thank you.  I've expanded the comment slightly into an answer.

Comment: @P. E. Dant - Thanks for the link. What does "it's who by a landslide on the OP's question" mean? You mean _who_ is more correct than _whom_ for Swan's sentence?

Comment: @William Yes, it's clearly _who._ This is a simple one. As stangdon says, phrase the clause as a sentence. Is it **We hope _he_ will be out of hospital soon** or **We hope _him_ will be out of hospital soon** ...? Obviously, it's the first one. **He** is the _subjective_ case of the third person masculine pronoun, so we use the _subjective case_ of the relative pronoun, which is **who.**

Comment: @William Before you move on: be sure to understand clearly the cases of pronouns. Even many native speakers don't remember the names and meanings of these elementary building blocks. They use the "right" one almost instinctively, but if you were to ask them, many could tell not you offhand the answer to "What is the objective case of the third person masculine pronoun?" or even "What does objective case mean?" As a learner of English, you should embed the information in your brain. Here's a [link](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/cases.htm) I chose, but there are thousands of others.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> This is a letter from my father, *whom* we hope will be out of hospital soon.

is understandable, but should be

> This is a letter from my father, *who* we hope will be out of hospital soon.

meaning

> ...we hope *he* will be to of the hospital soon.

If instead the sentence was phrased as

> ...we hope the hospital will release *him* soon.

your sentence could be phrased as

> This is a letter from my father, *whom* we hope the hospital will release soon.

However,

> This is a letter from my father, *who* we hope the hospital will release soon.

would probably also be understood.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about *whom* being used for objects.  The first sentence is more correct with *who*, but frankly you will probably hear a lot of people "hyper-correcting" it into *whom*, because they think that's more educated or more correct.

To tell whether you should use *who* or *whom*, try extracting the whom-clause from the rest of the sentence and see if it makes more sense with he/she or him/her.  If it's *he* or *she*, the subject pronouns, then it should be *who*, but if it's *him* or *her*, the object pronouns, then it should be *whom*.

For the first sentence,

> we hope __ will be out of hospital soon

We hope *him* will be out of hospital soon? No, we hope *he* will, so we should use *who*.

For the second sentence,

> you met ___ at my wedding last year

You met *her* at the wedding or you met *she* at the wedding?  In this case, you met *her*, so we should use *whom*.

Comment: Very concise and understandable. So, according to your explanation, the following is perfectly correct:
This is a letter from my father, whom we have not seen for ages. In this sentence, _whom_ is the subject of _see_, and for that _whom_ is the correct pronoun, right?

Comment: @William - Correct!

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I made a mistake. I meant "whom is the _object_ of seen" :)

Comment: @William Actually, you _didn't_ make a mistake. We "name" a verb as its infinitive, which in the case of your example is _see._

Comment: @P.E. Dant - It's not about _see_ vs. _seen_. The mistake I made was saying that _whom_ was the _subject_ while in fact it is the _object_ of the verb, be it _see_ or _seen_.

Comment: You're right, you were wrong. You were right about what was wrong, and I was wrong about what was wrong.